# Simple way to force javascript to always return an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I stumbled upon the [YQL API](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22North+America%22) to query for WOEIDs for use in Twitter, but I can see the output is not always in array. The API returns an object and I'm interested in value of `response.query.results` which returns the following:

- if there are no results, it returns null
- if there is only one result, it returns an object
- if the are multiple results, it returns an array

I want the result to always be an array. I can solve this by checking the result using the following code:

```
var count = response.query.count;

if(count === 0) {
    return [];
} else if(count === 1) {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(response.query.results);
    return arr;
} else {
    return response.query.results;
}
```

Is there a javascript or lodash function that can simplify the above code? It seems `_.forEach` and `_.toArray` will treat each property as an object if provided with a single object.

Comment: [].concat(response.query.results)

Comment: if count is 0 then what is the value if `response.query.results` ?

Comment: `[].concat(response.query.results || [])` To account for `null`

Comment: Yeah, seems we need to account for `null` otherwise the result will be `[null]` array with a length of 1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) with a default array if `response.query.results` is falsy.

```
return [].concat(response.query.results || []);
```

By having zero as value for `response.query.results`, you could take the [Nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) instead of [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR), which repects all values without `undefined` or `null`.

```
return [].concat(response.query.results ?? []);
```

Comment: Perfect. The previous answer `[].concat(count ? response.query.results : []);` returns `[null]` with a length of one. Thanks!

Comment: then use only the result set, if it returns a reliable truthy/falsy value.

Comment: doesn't work if, in my case, the value is `0`. :/

Answer (score 3):

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#concat

`_.concat([],response.query.results);`

would also do it.

but as @Brian pointed out, we need  to handle `null` being equivalent to `[]` so you can add

`_.concat([],_.isNull(response.query.results)?[]:response.query.results);`

note that this is more correct because it will work for results with falsey values (like `0` and `false` etc)

in general, lodash is more robust than built in javascript.  this usually works in your favour.  one place this can trip you up is if `results` was a string (which is an array of characters)

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.4/lodash.js#L6928

```
function concat() {
  var length = arguments.length;
  if (!length) {
    return [];
  }
  var args = Array(length - 1),
      array = arguments[0],
      index = length;

  while (index--) {
    args[index - 1] = arguments[index];
  }
  return arrayPush(isArray(array) ? copyArray(array) : [array], baseFlatten(args, 1));
}
```

Comment: This works too. Though just like the previous answer, you need to check for `null` with `_.concat([], response.query.results || [])`

Comment: good point.  of course, doing checks like that presumes you never return a falsey value.  otherwise, `0, false, null, undefined, NaN` etc will all result in an empty array instead of the real value.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Tom's answer above, the lodash function `castArray` (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#castArray), introduced in Lodash v4.4, could also work for this. It has the marginal benefit that its intent is slightly more clear that `[].concat(x)`

```js
const _ = require('lodash')

_.castArray(null) // [null]
_.castArray({a:1}) // [{a:1}]
_.castArray([{a:1},{a:2}] // [{a:1},{a:2}]
```

To deal with the null, considerations are similar to answers above, depending on how you want to handle unexpected values. A ternary with `_.isNull` would work, or else `??` is useful, e.g.:

```
const castArrayRemovingNullUndef = x => _.castArray(x ?? [])
const castArrayRemovingNull = x => _.castArray(_.isNull(x) ? [] :x)

_.castArrayRemovingNull(null) // []
_.castArrayRemovingNull({a:1}) // [{a:1}]
_.castArrayRemovingNull([{a:1},{a:2}] // [{a:1},{a:2}]
```